# How to hide slotted element before rendering the vue template in vueJs 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

See this images
i dont want to display here those elements
[image: I dont want to display here]

See the Below code sample
sample.blade.php

```
<create-form id= "create_form" title="Sample Form" >
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="form-label" for="multicol-username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" id="multicol-username" class="form-control" placeholder="john.doe" name="ma_user_id" data-type="varchar" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="form-label" for="multicol-email">Email</label>
      <div class="input-group input-group-merge">
        <input type="text" id="multicol-email" class="form-control" placeholder="john.doe" aria-label="john.doe" aria-describedby="multicol-email2" name="password" data-editmode="false" data-editname="email">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="multicol-email2">@example.com</span>
      </div>
    </div>
</create-form>
```

createForm.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="card mb-4" v-show="showForm">
    <h5 class="card-header">{{title}}</h5>
    <form class="card-body" id="createForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" ref="createForm">
      <div class="row g-3">
        <slot></slot>
        <div class="pt-4">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-sm-3 me-1" id="save_return">Submit</button>
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-label-secondary" @click="hideForm">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  props: ['title'],
  setup() {},
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
  created() {
  },
  mounted() {

  },
  methods: {
  },
}
</script>
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap')


import { createApp } from 'vue'
import createForm from './components/createForm';

const app = createApp({})

app.component('create-form', createForm);

app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: You may add a `isMounted` which will be `true` only after mounted, and put the `<slot/>` inside a `<template v-if="isMounted">`

Comment: You have a v-show directive but is it declared properly in your data object? `showForm` should default “false” if you don’t want to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the template that's rendered by the php backend to not be visible until vue is able to handle it, though I'm not 100% sure that's the case.

If that is the case, you could use the [`v-cloak` directive](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-cloak)

> This directive is only needed in no-build-step setups.
>
> When using in-DOM templates, there can be a "flash of un-compiled templates": the user may see raw mustache tags until the mounted component replaces them with rendered content.
>
> v-cloak will remain on the element until the associated component instance is mounted. Combined with CSS rules such as `[v-cloak] { display: none }`, it can be used to hide the raw templates until the component is ready.

```html
<create-form id="create_form" title="Sample Form" v-cloak>
...

<style>
  [v-cloak] { display: none }
</style>
```